# How do I display:none the Feature Image of all my posts for RSS?

Tags: css, rss

I currently have set the feature image to `display:none` for all my posts on my website but when a new post goes to rss it shows the feature image. How do I stop that from happening? If this isn't possible then my next question would be, how do I add a caption for a post to a Feature Image?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using Wordpress (by the fact you are using phrases "posts" and "featured image").

It is not possible to apply css-rules to your RSS so the answer is you need to remove it using a filter/action. Last time I checked Wordpress does not by default add the featured image into rss-feeds so probably your theme or some plugin is adding it. Disable that feature and you should be all set...

Comment: How do I add a filter/action so it takes the feature image out of the `<description>`. I can't disable the feature image because I need to use it for another part of my website.

Comment: Not sure of how you would remove it but if you can explain how you got it there I might be able to help. :) Care to share the url?